# How to capture and pass Mat object to a new activity?

Tags: java, opencv, android

I am planning on implementing ocr, the idea is for the user to capture an image and the app will write it as text to a file on the phone. I have managed to display the feed from the camera to the  javacameraview using CvCameraViewListener2.

I now want to capture the frame as an Mat object and pass it to a new activity. The solution's I saw all involve saving the photo, or displaying the processed image or live processing. I just need to pass the Mat to another class for processing then I can release it. I'm having trouble find a methodology for doing this though it seems as though it should be fairly straightforward.

The question is essentially how to get the Mat object from the cameraview?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you stackoverflow

The relevant code is here

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
Import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo; importandroid.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
Import android.widget.Toast;


        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != 90) {
                    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
                }
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraInit);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //marshmallow permissions
                        takePhoto();

                    }
                });
            }

            private void callCamera(){
                Intent startCameraIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OpenCVCamera.class);
                startActivity(startCameraIntent);
            }

            public void takePhoto() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        callCamera();
                    } else {
                        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
                            Toast.makeText(this, "This app requires camera access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
                    }
                } else {
                    callCamera();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

                if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT){
                    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        callCamera();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                } else {
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                }

            }
        }


    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.util.Log;

        import android.view.SurfaceView;
        import android.view.WindowManager;

            import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
            import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
            import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
            import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
            import org.opencv.core.Core;
            import org.opencv.core.Mat;

        public class OpenCVCamera extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{
        // need to correct view size (i think this can be done in the xml
        // else refer to cmaera video app
        // also orientation needs to be corrected

            private static final String TAG = "OpenCVCamera";
            private CameraBridgeViewBase cameraBridgeViewBase;

            private BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
                @Override
                public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                    switch (status) {
                        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                            cameraBridgeViewBase.enableView();
                            break;
                        default:
                            super.onManagerConnected(status);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_cvcamera);
                cameraBridgeViewBase = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
                cameraBridgeViewBase.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
                cameraBridgeViewBase.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume(){
                super.onResume();
                if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
                    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, baseLoaderCallback);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
                    baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCameraViewStopped() {

            }

            @Override
            public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
                //original just returns inputFrame.rgba()
                Core.rotate(inputFrame.rgba(), inputFrame.rgba(), Core.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE); //ROTATE_180 or ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE
                return inputFrame.rgba();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you see the samples @GitHub? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-3-cameracontrol
You should implement PictureCallBack, then you could create a Mat from a byte buffer: http://answers.opencv.org/question/9948/make-mat-from-buffer-byte/

Comment: Mat yo want to access in another class you can declare that mat as static in the current class. Now you can access this Mat in any class by using the name of the class in which you declared that Mat followed by a dot.